# How to design a scalable HTML5 website for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I need a scalable HTML5 website design. My idea is to define a "base" font-size of 1px in the body element and define all child elements relatively to this value in "em".

More precisely: All sizes (width, height, margin, padding and font-size) of the child elements (images, divs etc.) are defined in "em" units, so it is easy to scale the whole website only by changing the "base" font-size (in the body).

I need to do this since different mobile devices have different screen sizes and also different devicePixelRatio values.

So, if I detect a bigger screen size (e.g. 1.2x bigger) via JavaScript, I can simply set `font-size: 1.2px` just for the body element and the whole website should be 1.2x bigger.

**Example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>foo</title>

        <style>
            body{
                font-size: 1px;
                /* If a sceen is 1.2x bigger than this "default" size, then change font-size to 1.2px */
            }

            #myimg{
                /* 200em = 200px in this case because body font-size=1px */
                width: 200em;
                height: 200em;
            }

            #somediv{
                width: 100em;
                height: 100em;
                font-size: 20em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <img id="myimg" src="foo.jpg">
            <div id="somediv">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The only problem is that containers that have a font-size (e.g. 22em) defined, also define a new "base" font-size for their child elements, so this must be avoided.

**Example** style (Must not happen!)

```
#wrapper{
  font-size: 3px;
}
```

If this style above would have been added, all child containers (and their children) would become 3 times bigger (=not what I want).

Is this whole idea a practicable solution, or are there better ways to create a fully scalable design?

Comment: I think what you're talking about is called an "elastic layout". There's unending tips on how to do this correctly, not all of it good advice. Here's a decent article on the differences between fixed, fluid, and elastic layouts: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tried my solution described and it worked very well.
I also noted that this seems to be a pretty common practice.

The only thing that I recommend to change is to use a base font size of 10px (instead of 1px) and divide all child element by 10.

Comment: question owner accept this as correct answer then why -1? plz remove

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? For me this post correctly answered my question.